# How can I change a text depending on the form input? (show price right away)

Tags: wordpress

I have a site with a form where the customer can enter how many of a product that they need. Below the form the total price is displayed. If a customer enters for example 10 quantity, I want the price to be shown right away, for example 500€. If a customer enters 20 in the field it should display 1000€ right away, without refreshing the site. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple.

Have another input field in the form with the attribute set as read-only.
Write keyup event for the QUANTITY field and multiply the VALUE with the desired number as per your calculations and populate in the PRICE input field.

---

```
    <input type="number" name="quantity" id="quantity" />
    <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" readonly />

<script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('#quantity').keyup(function(){
    var qty = $('#quantity').val();

    $('#amount').val(qty * 50);    
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

Here is the JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/rajeevRF/Ltsp56ry/6/

Do let me know if you need more help on this